# Stripping line numbers from Julia AST

Tags: recursion, julia, metaprogramming, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using the following function to strip the line numbers from Julia ASTs:

```
function filter_lineno(ex::Expr)
           filter!(ex.args) do e
               isa(e, LineNumberNode) && return false
               if isa(e, Expr)
                   (e::Expr).head === :line && return false
                   filter_lineno(e::Expr)
               end
               return true
           end
           return ex
       end
```

But this doesn't seem to work properly when there are macros in the code. Here is a failing example:

```
expr = Meta.parse("begin run(``) end")
filter_lineno(expr)
```

I get the following error:

```
BoundsError: attempt to access 2-element Array{Any,1} at index [3]
```

Another example when processing docstrings:

```
expr = Meta.parse("begin \"Here is the doc\"\nmodule X end end")
filter_lineno(expr)
```

Yields the following:

```
quote
    Core.@doc module X
        end
end
```

What is wrong with this function, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the `MacroTools` package:

```
julia> using MacroTools

julia> cc = Meta.parse("begin \"Here is the doc\"\nmodule X end end")
quote
    #= none:1 =#
    #= none:1 =# Core.@doc "Here is the doc" module X
        #= none:2 =#
        #= none:2 =#
        end
end

julia> MacroTools.striplines(cc)
quote
    Core.@doc "Here is the doc" module X
        end
end
```

Comment: That doesn't work on nested structures. In that case you need `MacroTools.prewalk(rmlines, expr)` or `MacroTools.striplines(expr)`. If you edit the response I will be able to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I should have tested that with the second example instead of the first one. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is a duplicate question, which I've [answered here on SO before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53352175/7754070):
Just use `Base.remove_linenums!(ex)` and it should work (TM).

Comment: Works with the first example, but not the second example.

Comment: I don't think so, because it works in many cases and unlike the other response uses the core Julia functions.